# Pandas is condition on multiple columns

Tags: pandas, if-statement, contains

I have a dataframe

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
A         F      F      F
B         F      A      B
C         B      A      C
D         S      A      F
```

I want to say if A and F in any of these columns then make a new column and enter "Found"

```
col1    col2    col3    col4   output
A         F      F      F        Found
B         F      A      B        Found
C         B      A      C           0
D         S      A      F        Found
```

Comment: Use Booleans. Something like `df.eq('A').any(1) & df.eq('F').any(1)`.

Comment: use `df['output']=np.where(df.eq('A').any(1) & df.eq('F').any(1),'Found',0)`

Comment: @jpp long time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: ((x=='F').any() & (x=='A').any()).any(),axis=1), 'output'] = 'Found'`

`df.fillna(0)`

Comment: I think  you need to use '&' instead of '|' here to get the output.

Comment: Yes, you are correct Loochie, thanks for pointing it out .. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use :

```
df['output']=np.where(df.eq('A').any(1) & df.eq('F').any(1),'Found',0)
```

Another approach:

```
df['output']=(df.eq('A').any(1) & df.eq('F').any(1)).map({True:'Found',False:0})
```

---

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 output
0    A    F    F    F  Found
1    B    F    A    B  Found
2    C    B    A    C      0
3    D    S    A    F  Found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.DataFrame.where():

```
df.where(lambda x: (x=='A') | (x=='F')).dropna(thresh=1)
```